# How to inherit from a base C++ in Cython and pass `self` to inherited method

Tags: c++, callback, cython

I have the following library:

```
namespace worker {
class Worker {
public:
  virtual Worker();
  virtual void doWork() = 0; 
};

class Factory {
  public:
    void addWorker(std::unique_ptr<Worker> worker) {
      workers.push_back(std::move(worker));
    }
    void doWork() {
      for (auto& worker : workers) { worker->doWork(); }
    }
  private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Worker>> workers; 
};
}
```

I would like to wrap this in Cython and allow implementing workers in Python, pass them through Cython to C++. However, I don't know how to get `self` when inheriting:

```
cdef extern from "Worker.h" namespace "worker":
    cdef cppclass cWorker "worker::Worker":
        void doWork() except +

cdef cppclass WorkerWrapper(cWorker):
    object worker

    void __cinit__(self, object worker):
        self.worker = worker

    void doWork():
        # No self!
        self.worker.doWork()
```

Also, I don't know how to create workers because when I do:

```
make_unique[WorkerWrapp](worker_class())
```

I get:

```
Python object cannot be passed as a varargs parameter.
```

Comment: cython classes are python classes implemented in C, they cannot inherit from C++ classes, they have completely different ABI, you need to create an actual C++ class that inherits from your other C++ class, that stores and manages the lifetime of your python worker, and invokes the methods of your python worker.

Comment: @AhmedAEK Does this mean I need to create a PyWorker in C++ that will inherit from Worker, take a PyObject and in doWork call it? But then how do I call doWork on this object? And this object will call something like PyObject_CallMethod? But then I will need to all the type conversions myself?

Comment: python's C api is actually super simple to use, if your python worker implements the `__call__` method then you can just call [PyObject_CallNoArgs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/call.html#c.PyObject_CallNoArgs) and pass the `PyObject*` to it, and make sure you properly manage the lifetime of this `PyObject*` in your C++ code to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: No. It's undocumented and incomplete but you can define C++ types in Cython like you're trying to do. I don't know the answers to your exact questions off the top of my head though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue:

```
Python object cannot be passed as a varargs parameter.
```

is because `unique_ptr` is declared to Cython with a signature of `T unique_ptr(...)` to avoid Cython having to reason about the arguments. It won't accept reference counted types for `...` varargs definitions because it's hard to reason about what might happen to them.

In this case I think you've got two options:

1. Cast the object to a `PyObject*` (you get `PyObject` by `from cpython cimport PyObject`) - this is just an opaque pointer type from Python's point of view so it hides the "objectyness" from Cython. `make_unique[WorkerWrapp](<PyObject*>worker_class())`
2. Avoid `make_unique` in favour of `unique_ptr[WorkerWrapper](new WorkerWrapper(worker_class()))`

For the second question you just drop the `self` - inside `cppclass` it's implicit (like in C++):

```
    void doWork():
        worker.doWork()
```

(Personally I think this inconsistency might have been a mistake...)